# How to return 1 decimal place for the answer of this calculated Label in Adobe Flash Builder

Tags: android, adobe, flash-builder, decimal

I am writing code in Adobe Flash Builder for an Android application. I have written my code to do some math and return the answer to a label field. I would like to know how do I return this answer to show only 1 spot after the decimal. Here is the code

```
lblAnswer.text = String(Number ((sldrABSL.value) + 46.7)/28.7);
```

If there are any suggestions please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decimal places uses the tofixed property. It must be added at the end of the specified number that needs to contain the decimal place.

```
 'lblAnswer.text = String(Number ((sldrABSL.value) + 46.7)/28.7).toFixed(1);
```

The one specifies the number of decimal places that are used.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you have a string representing a number, which you want to be presented with only one decimal.

Fist of all, you'd have to convert the numeric value of the string to a double:

```
String stringOfNumber = "100.1233123";
Double number = Double.valueOf(stringOfNumber);
```

Secondly, you'd have to establish the format of which to represent the double (number of decimals):

```
DecimalFormat oneDigit = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
```

Set the digit to a (i.e) TextView:

```
myTextView.setText("" + oneDigit.format(number));
```

I think this should work. Is this kind of what you were asking?

Edit: Not super certain as to how to set it to a textview, but in java, printing it to screen works like this:

```
System.out.println(oneDigit.format(number));
```

Edit2: Oh, and you'll need to this import:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
```

Edit3:

```
TextView.setText("" + oneDigit.format(number));
```

works fine for me.

Comment: I am developing an Android application with Flash builder. The screen contains a label that is blank of which will hold the answer " lblAnswer". There is also a button which will generate the initial calculation. And there is also an Hslider which the user can select 100-300. I have the onclick method set to do the calculation. The only thing is the label is returning answers like this 7.222335453 rather than 7.2 How do I fix this. Every tutorial is giving me the conversion based on already having the initial number. I won't know the number until the calculation is done.

Comment: I am not familiar with Flash Builder, sorry. I googled a bit around, and it seems that something called fractionalDigits determines how many digits should appear after a decimal separator. Check this link: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/testdrive/articles/6_add_charts2.html

Comment: Thank you, I truly appreciate your quick response to this topic. I will check that reference and see. I am finding that Flash Builder is a bit different compared to the other IDE's but it also helps me learn the basic fundamentals of both IOS and Android , when comparing to development.